# Carousel Bootstrap desaparece asp net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-3

Boa noite, tentei encontrar a resposta dessa minha duvida no forum e não encontrei.
Tenho um site desenvolvido em Asp.Net MVC e na página inicial tenho um carousel em bootstrap. O carousel funciona normalmente, passa em slide 3 imagens. Percebi que depois de um tempo, as imagens desaparecem, e o carousel para de funcionar. Fica exibindo somente os tres pontinhos embaixo, que representa quando vc quer clicar em um dos slides. Tentei rastrear o código e não estou conseguindo chegar numa solução para entender porque o carousel para de exibir as imagens sempre depois de um tempo que ele é exibido.

```
<section id="slider">
<!--slider-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div id="slider-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="100000" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#slider-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#slider-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#slider-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h1><span>Stile</span> Speciale</h1>
                            <p>Lindo conjunto Cropped de Pelinho e Calça com Listra! </p>
                            @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-default get">Get it now</button>*@
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <a href="/produto/0019">
                                <img src="Stile/Conjunto Cropped Pelinho e Calça Listra.jpg" class="girl img-responsive" alt="" width="500" height="400" />
                                @*<img src="images/home/pricing.png" class="pricing" alt="" />*@
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h1><span>Stile</span> Speciale</h1>
                            <h2>Calça Moletom</h2>
                            @*<p>Body da Jeiza da novela!! </p>*@
                            @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-default get">Get it now</button>*@
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <a href="/produto/0005">
                                <img src="Stile/Calça Moletom.jpg" class="girl img-responsive" alt="" width="500" height="400" />
                            </a>
                            @*<img src="images/home/pricing.png" class="pricing" alt="" />*@
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h1><span>Stile</span> Speciale</h1>
                            <h2>Blusa de Tule</h2>
                            @*<p>Body da Jeiza da novela!! </p>*@
                            @*<button type="button" class="btn btn-default get">Get it now</button>*@
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <a href="/produto/0001">
                                <img src="Stile/Blusa de Tule.jpg" class="girl img-responsive" alt="" width="500" height="400" />
                                @*<img src="images/home/pricing.png" class="pricing" alt="" />*@
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <a href="#slider-carousel" class="left control-carousel hidden-xs" data-slide="prev">
                        @*<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>*@
                    </a>
                    <a href="#slider-carousel" class="right control-carousel hidden-xs" data-slide="next">
                        @*<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>*@
                    </a>
                </div>

            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual a versão do Bootstrap?

Comment: "bootstrap" version="3.0.0"

Comment: Deixei meia-hora aqui rodando e não teve problema.

Comment: Hospedei o projeto nesse link [link] (http://stilespeciale.gear.host/) , depois de um tempo as imagens do slide continuam sumindo e não voltam.